# Django ORM Multicolumn join

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Users of my app are able to block other users so blocked users won't see their blockers anywhere in the app. I have following models

```
class User(models.Model):
    blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', symmetrical=False, through='Block')


class Block(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('from_user', 'to_user')

    from_user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='blocked')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='blocked_by')
```

So now I'm trying to make Django do the following query that will return users who didn't block currently logged in user.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
LEFT OUTER JOIN block ON (block.from_user_id = user.id AND block.to_user_id = 1)
WHERE block.id is null
```

where `1` is an id of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

what about `.exclude()` ?

```
User.objects.exclude(blocked_by__to_user__id=request.user.id)
```

maybe more efficient something like:

```
User.objects.filter(user__blocked_by__to_user=request.user.id, blocked_by__is_null=True)
```

Comment: This queryset generates query that uses subquery for excluding. That's much less efficient than joins

Comment: i cannot reproduce your setup now, but just updated the answer with a hint. As your M2M references self, you should have available the self relationship to filter with.